# low latency stream from raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I run following program on raspberry pi:

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --codec libav --libav-format mpegts -o "udp://address:port"
```

and on my laptop:

```
ffplay.exe udp://address:port -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -framedrop
```

However the resulting stream has about 1,5s delay while on my wifi. My target is to use to stream via lte, so latency will probbly be even higher. Is it possible to reduce latency?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider gstreamer for low-latency applications.

On the raspberry pi 4 (bullseye, gstreamer 1.18.4) run following command (after adjusting the host ip address of the receiver)

```
gst-launch-1.0 libcamerasrc ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.100 port=5200
```

On the laptop (bullseye, gstreamer 1.18.4) access the stream as follows

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, payload=96 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! queue !  fpsdisplaysink
```

This provides another example http://imrid.net/?p=4396 and it was also discussed here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121789/gstreamer-stream-low-latency-video-from-raspberry-pi-tx-to-raspberry-pi-rx